# how can we remove delimiter from account sidebar?

Tags: magento2.4.2

How to remove this lines on account sidebaar

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These line are added using XML file in `customer_account.xml` file. You can remove these XML block by below XML code.

```
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-delimiter-1" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-delimiter-2" remove="true" />
```

I hope it will help!